# ¿Por qué el Método PREPARE de PHP me arroja ERROR FATAL?

Tags: php

Php me arroja el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php y sql/practice/zend.php:17 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php y
>   sql/practice/zend.php on line 17

Lo que se me ocurre es que pueda estar exigiendo que incluya el campo '`id`' (y su valor) en la consulta del `PREPARE`, pero para mi hacer eso no tiene sentido porque se supone que los valores del campo '`id`' se generan solos automáticamente.

```
<?php
$MARIA = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", 
"EMPLOYER");

if ( $MARIA->connect_error ) {
  echo "Falló la conexión!";
} else {
  $PRE = $MARIA->prepare( "INSERT INTO EMPLOYER 
  (nombre, sexo, edad, puesto, sueldo, correo, 
  movil, casa) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
  );
  $PRE->bind_param('ssisfsis', $nombre, $sexo, 
  $edad, $puesto, $sueldo, $correo, $movil, 
  $casa);

  $nombre = 'Gian'; 
  $sexo = 'Hombre';
  $edad = 25;
  $puesto = 'Marketing';
  $sueldo = 3.500;
  $correo = 'gian@mark.es';
  $movil = 989543723;
  $casa = 'Av. Los Sauces';

  $PRE->execute();

  echo "Los datos fueron enviados!";

  $MARIA->close();
}
?>
```

[image: base de datos EMPLOYER]

Comment: Tu gestor de bases de datos no requiere contraseña?

Comment: Esta todo por defecto. Se supone que por defecto viene con el usuario ROOT y sin contraseña. Hice la prueba con el metodo CONNECT_ERROR y me arroja que estoy conectado.

Comment: El valor de la variable sueldo es *tres mil quinientos* o *tres punto cinco*?? si bien tu campo es float los ceros a la derecha confunden un poco... Como sujerencia también sería bueno que pongas las asignaciones al principio del else

Comment: Es tres mil quinientos. Cuando dices "las asignaciones" te refieres a izar o subir todas las variables al principio del else, antes de prepare y bind?

Comment: Victor Hugo tenias razon, la base de datos no me reconoce 2.500, me muestra 2.5. ¿POr que , y que hago?

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucioné el problema yo mismo. Era un error mío, en el INSERT estaba escrito mal el nombre de la tabla, el cual era DATOS, en lugar de EMPLOYER (employer es la base de datos, me confundí). Segundo: En bind_param('ssisfsis' ) No existe el argumento F (de float) sino D (de double). Corrigiendo ambas cosas, funcionó. Disculpen las molestias.